# Looking for a JavaScript multi-level picklist DATE-PICKER widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am looking for a sample of a date picker widget (for faster selection of Date Of Birth) that is in the form of a multi-level dropdown, like this:

```
Field
   |
   |      1970
   -----YearSelect
          1971
          1972
          1973
          ...
           |             March
           ----------MonthSelect
                         April
                         May
                          ...
                           |           15
                           ---------DaySelect
                                       16
                                       17
                                       ...
```

Has anyone made such a thing yet or do I need to make one?  Suggestions or hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/jquery-dtpicker/.

Comment: out of curiosity, i am curious what a DWR/Ajax solution might look like, in relation to my question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why would you need to query the server for this? And if querying the server isn't involved, Ajax becomes just JavaScript, which this plugin is. I'm confused... :)